# Romper una sentencia if en react native

Tags: android-studio, react-native

Tengo una base de datos json en la que tengo usuarios con un nombre y una contraseña para que se puedan logear en mi app.

A la hora de hacer el fetch y hacer la validación del usuario y la contraseña contra la base de datos tengo un error; si la contraseña y el usuario introducidos por el usuario coinciden con los de la base de datos, pasa a la pantalla principal y si no salta un alert diciendo que hay un error. Pues bien, si el usuario y la contraseña coinciden con la base de datos, pasa correctamente a la pantalla principal pero aún así salta el alert de que ha habido un error y no se muy bien el por qué. 
Os adjunto mi código.

```
export class LoginPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: [],
      validated: false,
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/usuaris'
    };
  }

  getData = () => {
    this.setState({isLoading: true})
    fetch(this.state.url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {

      this.setState({
        dataSource: res,
        isLoading: false
      })
      let filter = this.state.dataSource.filter(item => {
        if(item.username == this.state.username && item.password == this.state.password){
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', { username: this.state.username });
          return;
        }else{
          alert("Error")
        }
      })
      this.setState({
        dataSource: filter,
      })

    });
  };

  render(){

    return(
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>

          <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
              <Image source={require('../images/floridaLogo.png')} style={{width: 250}}></Image>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.void}></View>

          <View style={styles.textContainer}>

              <TextInput
                  placeholder="Nombre de usuario"
                  placeholderTextColor="rgba(253,110,110,1)"
                  style={styles.name}
                  maxLength={12}
                  onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
                  value={this.state.username} 
              ></TextInput>
              <View style={styles.underline}></View>

              <TextInput
                  placeholder="Contraseña"
                  placeholderTextColor="rgba(253,110,110,1)"
                  style={styles.name}
                  onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                  value={this.state.password} 
              ></TextInput>
              <View style={styles.underline}></View>

          </View>

          <View style={styles.buttonLoginContainer}>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonLogin} onPress ={ () => this.getData()}>
              <Text style={styles.textButton}>Acceder</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una mala idea hacer la autorización en el cliente, ya que tienes que transmitir la información al cliente y luego confiar en su decisiones. Sería más fiable hacerla en tu servidor.

Es muy fácil para mi (o cualquier persona) ir a tu servidor y obtener toda la información (contraseñas incluidas) sobre tus usuarios. O hacer una aplicación que lo hace.

Es una mala idea guardar las contraseñas en texto plano. Tienes que guardar una representación de la contraseña como el cache (por ejemplo SHA256).

Tu sistema tiene que hacer esto:

1. Usuario transmite su nombre y contraseña de manera segura (https) a tu servidor.
2. Servidor calcula la representación de contraseña.
3. Servidor verifica si tiene un usuario con el mismo nombre y representación de contraseña.
4. Si tiene el usuario servidor repuesta con código 200 (OK) y la aplicación dice que esta autorizando.
5. Si no tiene el usuario servidor respuesta con código 401 (Unauthorized) y la aplicación dice que tiene un error.